# firebase Database Query Swift not reading

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each users of my app will answer a series of questions. I have successfully written those answers to my database (yah me!) in the following structure (see attached pic too [link to database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P624c.png)):
Database Structure:

```
     - driverQuestions
          - 'userId' (this the UID generated at authentication)
             - answers  (this is the answer that I need to display in the users profile for future reference   
             - questions (this is the question that the user has answered)
```

Database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "driverQuestions": {
      "$userId": {
      ".indexOn": "answers"
      }
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I have attempted to query my database with this code:

```
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

let userId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

ref?.child("driverQuestions").child(userId!).child("answers").queryOrdered(byChild: "answers").queryEqual(toValue: userId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
               print(postDict)
```

I get nothing printed in my consul. I think that the issue is that the userId is unique, but I am not sure what to do about it.... can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to be able to get the stored answers out of the database for the logged in user

Let me know if you require any further clarification

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are querying the answers node instead of the user, for child nodes with key "answers" which by your post doesn't seem to exist unless you have further nested nodes in your answers JSON. Otherwise please update your full data structure and let me know. So you are looking in driverQuestions/userId/answers/answers instead of driverQuestions/userId/answers

Removed sample code, this was irrelevant.

Try this to get all data for the user printed in the console:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("driverQuestions").child(userId!).observe(.value, with: {snapshot in 
    let answersData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
    print(answersData)
})
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to read my post! Great explanation and it makes sense.... unfortunately nothing is being printed into the consul!! Any other suggestions??? Are you sure that my code pertaining to userId is correct? any other suggestions how to handle using unique IDs ???

Comment: The way you have the data structured will work. A node of driver questions, a random UID key, and data for that node. I updated my answer to get all user data instead of just data in the answers node of the passed user. Maybe the UID you were passing had no answer data which would print nothing.

Comment: Hey this was also a problem I didn't see before: var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!  If you want to create a root reference the better way to do it is with let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

Comment: @mathew - you are the man!! .... I did change the reference as you suggested today... and ... no help   : (    .... I made your changes and now I am getting [ : ] in consul which I think means that I am pulling an empty array from my database. So an improvement, but need more.... any more thoughts????

Comment: Wait! Hold the presses - you were correct on the code above! I had too much code  with querys etc.... so thanks for the help!